# Updating a select menu using php, and mysql database, together with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I was wondering if someone can point me out to a tutorial that can help me achieve the following

I have two Select menus, when i click the first one i need the second one to populate based on the first menu selection. another problem is that when i update the form the select menu does not display the earlier selected item, the first item on the list is displayed. i need the select menu to display the last value that the user selected instead of displaying the select menu from the beginning. i need a good tutorial that can help me go through this step by step. thank you very much in advance for your support.

```
        <select name="cata" id="cat">
       <?php  while($cata = $query->fetch()){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cata->name;?>"><?php echo $cata->name;?></option>
        </select>
                <?php }?>
        <select name="subcata" id="subcat">           
       <?php while($subCata = $query->fetch()){?>
        <option value="<?php echo subCata->name;?>"><?php echo subCata->name;?></option>
      <?php  }  ?>                  
        </select>
```

Comment: While its a php function it should be inside <?php while(...) { ?> and your end <?php } ?>

Comment: that is not an issue, i am aware of that. but the problem how do you repopulated the values from previuse selection, meaning how can i pull the value from the database and disply it to the user based on his selection

Comment: I already updated the code. can you please help with the main issue.

Comment: on the run time after submiting the form you just have to check if the value that you sent over POST or GET is defined and on the loop it matchs the value so would be something like this: <?php if(!empty($_GET['cata'] && $_GET['cata'] === $cata->name) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>

Comment: where do insert selected="selected"

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of what you want to have please ? You can use the code snippet to do so. I am fallen in your explaination around where the form doesn't keep the previous data displayed.